# htaccess - passing a get variable to a new get variable.. with a redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, get

I need to redirect a page of an old site to a new one and pass the get variables along. At the moment the urls are as follows:

```
http://www.example.com/lang_english/customer_feedback/sample-forms/attachments-form/forma.php?order=123&dept=ABC
```

These now need to redirect to the following:

```
http://en.example.com/customer-feedback/customer-feedback?orderref=123&division=ABC
```

So the new URL is already an SEF one generated by Joomla, but the variables have to be passed as they are above. I've tested the below but am not getting the result I want...

```
RewriteRule lang_english/customer_feedback/sample-forms/attachments-form/forma.php/order=(.*)$&dept=(.*) http://en.example.com/customer-feedback/customer-feedback?orderref=$1&division=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Would anyone be able to offer any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong?

The customers will continue to receive the old URL but it needs to redirect properly to the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} order\=([^\&]*)\&dept\=([^\&]*)
RewriteRule ^lang_english/customer_feedback/sample-forms/attachments-form/forma\.php http://en.example.com/customer-feedback/customer-feedback?orderref=%1&division=%2 [R,QSA,L]
```